# I have list of files in directory, need to take files iwth common name as input in descending order

Tags: python

Example:
`FileA.txt`, `Uknown.txt`, `aplog`, `Aplog.01`, `Aplog.03`,`APlog.04` etc.
I want to read files starting from `aplog` in descending order and use that as a input for further handling. As of now i have hardcoded my filenames. I need to make it variable.

I have hardcoded input file names, want to make it variable.

import fileinput
    import re
    import os

```
index1 = 0
index2 = 0
line = 0
list1 = 0
path1 = ['aplog.20', 'aplog.19', 'aplog.18', 'aplog.17' , 'aplog.16' , 'aplog.15' , 'aplog.14' , 'aplog.13' , 'aplog.12' , 'aplog.11' , 'aplog.10' , 'aplog.09' , 'aplog.08' , 'aplog.07' , 'aplog.06', 'aplog.05' , 'aplog.04' , 'aplog.03' , 'aplog.02' , 'aplog.01' , 'aplog']
path2 = "aplog_Final.txt"

with open(path2, "a+") as f2:
    for fname in path1:
        with open(fname ,encoding="utf8") as f1:
            list1 = f1.readlines() 
            for line in list1:
                index1 = index1 + 1
                searchObj = re.search( r'(([Pp]ython) | ([He]llo))', line, re.M|re.I)
                if searchObj:
                    print ("Match Found at line %d" %(index1 ))
                    f2.writelines(line)
                else:
                    print ("No Match Found at line %d" %(index1 ))

f2.close()
```

I want to make this input file names, as variable. Need to read list of files from Folder, with key word `aplog` and sort it in descending order.

Comment: Do you have a common pattern? Like always ending with ".##"?

Comment: Hint: By using a `with` block for opening a file you don't have to close it explicitely, that's done automatically, so delete `f2.close()`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will delete f2.close().

Comment: Yes I have a Pattern, I need file names starting from "aplog" to be sorted in descending order. and ignore rest. there is no Extension for file names.

Answer (score 2):

By using `glob` module, you get a list of all files starting with `aplog` (case insensitive) by

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('/your_path/aplog*.*')
```

you can then iterate over it by

```
for fname in files:
    ...
```

and over the reversed list:

```
for fname in sorted(files, reverse=True):
    ...
```

Comment: @HARPAL, that is because it just sorting by `str`, and string order is sth like: `"1", "2", "20", "4"`

Answer (score 1):

This returns a list of the files in a given directory:

```
files = [f for f in listdir(filepath_in) if isfile(join(filepath_in, f))]
```

You can then iterate through the list and select the files you want. An alternative is to use the glob module, but I am too unfamiliar with it to provide an example.

Documentation on the glob module can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 1):

This code only solve your problem when the suffix of file name is integer, if not, you can see other answers.

```py
# your code
folder_path = '/folder/to/aplog/files/'
files = os.listdir(folder_path)    # list of files inside folder
aplog_files = [f for f in files if f.startswith("aplog")] # list of "aplog" files
aplog_suffix_sort = [int(s.lstrip("aplog.")) for s in aplog_files].sort(reverse=True)  # sorting based on the suffix - int
with open(path2, "a+") as f2:
    for suf in aplog_suffix_sort:
        fname="aplog.{}".format(suf)
        with open(fname ,encoding="utf8") as f1:
            list1 = f1.readlines() 
# your code
```